# How does STD work?

Tags: c++

I just started C++ and started doing basic text to console programs. In the book that I'm reading (Which is pretty old, I think) it uses cout to write stuff to the screen. Simple enough, right? But when I try to write cout it says that it's not defined. I searched around the internet and it said that I need std::cout or using namespace std; How does this stuff work? Explain it to me like you would to a 5 year old. I'm next level stupid.

Comment: Your book should explain this. If it doesn't, get a better book. *The C++ Programming Language* by *Bjarne Stroustrup* will suffice.

Comment: The name of the standard output stream is `std::cout`. Don't do `using namespace std;`.

Comment: List of recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: (`I'm next level stupid` (Don't _call_ it stupid - use _dense_.) Let me introduce you to [rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_ducking).)

Answer (score 0):

`std` is the namespace which contains all functions and classes of the standard library. [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) are used to avoid clashes of functions/classes with the same name. You can define a namespace `northern_guy` which contains a class `cout`.

```
std::cout << "output"; //prints to standard output
northern_guy:cout << "output"; //does what ever is defined in that namespace
```

(For this example you need to overload the << operator)

So you can use both functions/classes alongside in your code. That's why you should not use `using namespace std;`